# Which partitions can be deleted?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have ubuntu 15.10 and windows 10 installed on my laptop, but I have also other 9 partitions, and I don't know if I need them and which of those I can safely delete in order to increase size of other partitions. Here is a screenshot of Gparted:

[image]

I specify that I actually use both windows and ubuntu, so I want to preserve partitions *needed* by windows.

Thank you.

Comment: You have **182.52GB** of non-allocated space - Why not begin with utilizing that?... Other partitions include other OS - Windows, and small "diagnosis" partitions (which is not reserved, just suggested).
Depends on your other OS - you might be able to "shrink" it down a bit, and expand others.

Answer (score 1):

According to your screenshot, it seams that you have samsung recovery partitions (factory image). 
If you don't need any recovery functions of your Samsung laptop, you can remove these.

More on here related: https://superuser.com/questions/626479/what-are-hidden-partitions-on-a-samsung-laptop-for

Comment: Thank you. Do you know what sda10 is and if I can delete that safely?

Comment: @Marc: We cannot judge by just looking at your screenshot. Maybe, you should try to mount this parition under Linux and/or Windows in order to see if there is any _usefull_ data to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell what each partition is by the `flag` and `mount point` options.

- `/dev/sda1` = Windows diagnostic partition, Widows needs this for recovery mode, but it is not required, you can do manual back up.
- `/dev/sda1` = EFI Boot partition, this is your boot partition
- `/dev/sda3` = This is a Windows reserved space partition, but says it is corrupted, you don't need this to boot Windows [source](http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/221302-how-eliminate-100mb-windows-reserved-space.html)
- `/dev/sda4` = This is the Windows C drive
- `/dev/sda5` = Another Windows diagnostic partition
- `/dev/sda6` = This is the Ubuntu / drive
- `/dev/sda7` = This is Linux swap, Ubuntu needs this
- `/dev/sda8` = Yet another Windows diagnostic partition
- `/dev/sda9` = Nothing
- `/dev/sda10` = A broken or corrupted partition, delete this.
- `/dev/sda11` = Samsung diagnostic partition, you can remove this if
  you don't need it (this is big it probably contains a back up)
- `/dev/sda12` = This will be a boot partition for `/dev/sda11`

I don't know why you have three Windows diagnostic partitions (back ups ?), I can't say what one you need for your install, you can remove these but it may break Windows recovery, remove the Samsung ones if you want and remove the corrupted ones.

In `gparted` You can right click any partition and choose `mount` to view its contents in a file browser.